# Require JPM not define all JS

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I am currently developing a firefox extension with jpm.when I make an `jpm init`  I have a js file `index.js`. In this file I can include different sdk with `require` for example `var system = require("sdk/system");`
The problem is that if I have another js file I attach to my tab, I go well at my job but worries if I want to include an SDK in the file I get an error

> Require is no defined

`Require` only works in index.js file. How to access a sdk in different js file? Because I want to use the sdk `sdk/request` to query xmlHttpRequest

Comment: Don't you try to load sdk modules in the content script? If so, it's not allowed, but you can use XMLHttpRequest in those scripts without any module, as it's a part of window global object.

Comment: Or maybe you can even use [.fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch) for a nicer API in the content script. If you want to do cross-site requests, you'll have to [set a flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json#permissions) for it.

Comment: This link help me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818321/how-can-i-use-xmlhttprequest-from-main-js-in-a-firefox-addon-sdk-extension-or